# ajax request duplicate return result while displaying

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

Display the result here at **displayResult**---

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <div align="center" class="col-md-10">
                <input  type="text" id= "contentSearch" name="contentSearch" class="form-control">
            </div></div>
        <div class="form-group"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="submitSearch">Search
            </button></div>                
    </form>
</div>

<div id="displayResult">
    {% for result in chris%}{{ result.name }}{%endfor%}  
</div>
```

and in **ajax success**--

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#searchform").on('submit', function (e) {
            var data = {};
            data['contentSearch'] = $('#contentSearch').val();

            $.ajax({
                url: '/ourserver/applicants/istiak/home',
                type: 'post',
                data: data,
                success: function (returnedData) {
                    $("#displayResult").html(returnedData);// display
                }
            });

            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

But while displaying the result it is creating a from again--

**before make the request** ---
[image]

**After the request when display the result --**
[image]

So it is creating the form again and also displaying the result based on the value as well.

Like if the return result is 2 time than it display twice, if the result have 3 values it will display 3 times.

so how it is possiblr to stop being duplicate from and just only display the result !!

Not multiple times, just once !!!

Anyone knows how it can be solved !!!

Comment: please post all relevant code like the entire ajax

Comment: @Pekka i have updated the question

Comment: Can you post HTML code?

Comment: can you check in the console and post here the response of the ajax call?

Comment: @AnkitSaroch yes i have update the html code as well

Comment: @IsakJohnsson did you try to check what is the response from ajax?are you sure it is not double?

Comment: @Pekka no i didn't, how can i check the response from ajax !

Comment: @IsakJohnsson seems you have got the full html page in your response.

Comment: might be the case, that your ajax call is returning the whole html page, and you are placing it within the display result. So, kind of nested pages are coming within the `displayResult`

Comment: @IsakJohnsson you are re-rendering the whole twig file in ajax into `displayResult` div

Comment: @Jai so how can i only display the results not the whole html page in response !!

Comment: @IsakJohnsson only return the required html, or return the result in JSON and create the html on the page.

Comment: @AnkitSaroch can you kindly show a example how to do that !

Comment: @IsakJohnsson just return the data rather than sending the whole html page in response with data

Comment: @Isak 
suppose if you are using node 
`app.get('path',function(req,res){
   //your logic
  res.json(data);

})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to extract the target html like this:

```
$("#displayResult").html($(returnedData).find("#displayResult").html());// display
```

Comment: Awesome it stops creating the form again, but it is still displaying the results multiple times, i mean if the result have 3 values it is displaying 3 times, how can i stop that too as well, can you kindly suggest something !

Comment: why not just return the data as json and append them on table or list?

Comment: @Jai i have also updated the pic what it is displaying

Comment: `{% for result in chris%}{{ result.name }}{%endfor%}` do you have this in any other loop @IsakJohnsson?

Comment: @Jai oops my bad there was a loop, sorry  and thanks a lot for your awesome answer

Comment: @IsakJohnsson you are welcome and glad this helped you.